# optimum solution for running C programs with graphics.h header file on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, gcc, graphics

I want to make it clear that I know there are better ways to write graphics programs but our teacher is using turbo c++ program on windows with graphics.h header file.
As I am using Linux kali distro, I wanted an optimum solution to run C programs with graphics.h header file. problem is graphics.h is not the part of the standard GCC library.

now there are multiple approaches to solve this issue:

1. installing turbo c++ and DOSBox
2. adding “graphics.h” C/C++ library to GCC compiler in Linux
3. downloading a compiler which has graphics.h library.
   (i don't know how much of it makes sense but I wrote what I wrote according to my basic understanding.)

now let's get to solutions,

I didn't try the first one. I wanted a more optimum solution if there's one. you can describe all of the solutions so I can have a better understanding of this one.

the second solution is to get dependencies and necessary packages. for this, I looked into this article:
[How to add “graphics.h” C/C++ library to gcc compiler in Linux](https://pastebin.com/SvxfQSfa)

it was 4 step process:

1. **Get build-essentials.** *done*.
   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. **Additional packages.** *partially done*.
   `sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 \ guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \ libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \ libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \ libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev`

the command above gives the following error:

> E: unable to locate package libesd0-dev
> [image: screenshot]

so here I can either find the package by adding some repository in source list but I don't want to break my system. I can find the package online somehow but I don't know where I should place the files. Also, it brings me to the question where did the above packages got installed?

3. **download and install libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz file** *partially done*

I downloaded the file, extracted it. ran command `./configure`
and then when I ran `make` it gave me the following output on the terminal. (i want to give you the insights but it gave 1 fatal error if you ignore the warnings. )

> guile-libgraph.c:25:10 fatal error: libguile.h: no file or directory found.

link of Pastebin below:
[make command output](https://pastebin.com/SvxfQSfa)

I tried other solutions such as the one suggested on this link:
[Trying to install libgraph](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-trying-to-install-libgraph/)

the best solution mentioned:
[image: Trying to install libgraph]

using the alternative method,
the output I got was:
[make command output](https://pastebin.com/eHpxppAn)

no errors and just warning so I moved forward with `make install` command. I got the following errors as output:
[finally, make install](https://pastebin.com/UjV6xuXn)

As u can see I am stuck. thanks for reading. please help.

> the main objective is to run C programs with graphics.h on Linux kali.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, don't [paste screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, and the text is not accessible to google searches. In addition, contributors trying to help will have to type-copy any commands etc. when trying to reproduce the problem. Instead, copy-and-pase the console output into your question with appropriate formatting.

Comment: Please be aware that Kali Linux isn't a good educational environment.  Dependency problems on Kali, like the ones you're experiencing, appear to be far too common and difficult to fix.  ...Leading me to say bluntly: Kali isn't good generally.

Comment: Having said that, `libguile.h` is missing because you didn't successfully install libguile-2.0 in step 2.  You could try to install just this one package, to see if dependencies will let you.  To execute `make install` you may need "root" permissions.  IE run this command as root.  Sorry I can't help you more than that.

Comment: A few things to note: Turbo C++ is almost 30 years old.  Even if you can find a package that includes `graphics.h` and the associated libraries, are you sure the API hasn't changed in the last 30 years?

Comment: As i said, i do understand it is old and is not used now. But for learning purpose i need it as it is being used by my teacher in class. I don't want to use it. It's too old and deprecated for making graphics but i have to catch up with class. So i don't have libguile-2.0 because there's no such package in linux kali official repo. Can i get an alternative solution? Even if it's not perfect. I Just want it to be usable for learning purpose. And i won't be using it in real life projects. So I don't really understand what it has to do with API.

Comment: If it's not possible to directly run it on linux kali. Then you can suggest me instructions to set it up on virtual machine or docker. If it's possible. (Docker would be better i think)

Comment: You might want to point out to your teacher that the environment he's using is WAY obsolete and maybe should consider using something more up-to-date , like Cygwin or GCC.

Comment: Actually i did tell that to teacher. Obviously she knew it. But i think it really doesn't matter if it's graphics.h or opengl because we are implementing basic graphics algorithms and anything that can plot pixels would do the job. Subject is computer graphics. So we are learning to draw graphics using maths and algorithms instead of predefined functions from graphics.h.

Comment: "_Subject is computer graphics_" - then don't use Kali, which is a specialist security pen-testing distribution

Answer (score 1):

I wrote SDL_bgi exactly to provide a portable, modern, and fast 'GRAPHICS.H' implementation that is compatible with the original Borland compiler for DOS. It can be downloaded from http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/

To compile and install it on any GNU/Linux distro, do:

```
$ tar zxvf SDL_bgi-2.4.4.tar.gz # or later release
$ cd SDL_bgi-2.4.4/src
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Files will be installed in appropriate directories:

```
SDL_bgi.h      ->  /usr/include/SDL2/
graphics.h     ->  /usr/include/
libSDL_bgi.so  ->  /usr/lib/
```

To compile a graphics program with SDL_bgi:

```
$ gcc -o program program.c -lSDL_bgi -lSDL2
```

Happy graphics programming!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking into the issue i realised that you cannot run it directly on linux kali because programs with graphics.h requires packages that are not present in official repository of Linux kali. But if you particularly need to compile and run code which uses graphics.h header file (for educational purposes), you will need a DOSBOX emulator on which you can install turbo c++ IDE by borland.

Follow the steps below:

1. Install `dosbox` and `turbo c++` ([Run Turbo C++ using DOSBox on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.google.com/amp/s/rupinderjeetkaur.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/run-turbo-c-using-dosbox-on-ubuntu-14-04/amp/))
2. Set path for libs and include directories  ([Turbo C++ error: Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'](https://developerinsider.co/turbo-cpp-error-unable-to-open-include-file-stdio-h/amp/))
3. Incase of linker error, do this:

   Options -> linker -> libraries

   Check the graphics library by clicking on it once (you will see a 'X' in checkbox after the click) and press "Ok"

Test if it works by compiling and running code using turbo c++.